# Can we force limited-access to a group of users even if they access SharePoint from managed devices

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, access, azure

I am reading this link which describe how to set limited-access to users who access sharepoint from un-managed devices

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#limit-access

But my question is if we can force limited access to a group of users even if they access SharePoint from managed devices? Or limited access can only be configured for unmanaged devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create customized Conditional Access policy in [Azure Active Directory](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ConditionalAccessBlade/Policies) to specific users to limit access to SharePoint regardless of from managed devices or not.

Reference: [Building a Conditional Access policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-policies)